# Need help in unlocking LG G2 LS980ZVC, running on KitKat

Tags: sim-unlocking, htc-desire-z, lg

I am looking for a working link to a tutorial explaining how to globally unlock LG G2 LS980 (Android Version 4.4.2, Software Version LS980ZVC).

I tried several, but can't unlock the phone. Most pages say "Total Commander doesn't work on KitKat". I've rooted the phone already. And Root Checker confirms the same.

Can anyone suggest a link or method to unlock the phone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarification: What does "Total Commander" have to do with "SIM lock", as you've used that tag? Could it be you rather mean [bootloader-unlock](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bootloader-lock/info)?

Comment: Total Commander helps copy/delete files to/from the phone, via PC, to make phone skip the locked network registration process.

Comment: I have come down to this. As soon as I restart the phone after deleting the **telephony.db** file (which should stop the phone looking for Sprint), the file gets regenerated. And also, Kitkat does not allow Total Commander to copy files to phone. I had to do that in Root Explorer.